# Using Knockout Observable Array to Add dynamic UI element

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my problem that I am struggling with.

1- I am using the mapping plugin to create a Knockout ViewModel. From server side I have a complex object that has several properties (not relevant to this question). Besides other properties I have a property TotalofExpenses and also have one List called Expenses (An expense item is an object that has amount and description). Mapping plugin turn this list into ObservableArray and TotalofExpenses into observalbe

2- On the UI I want to achieve following

- Initially I want to present an input for Expense Item. Two input boxes (one for amount and one for description)
- Once User add description and expense amount (both), I want to present input boxes for another expense item and display total of current expenses somewhere (say at the bottom of the table). As user keep adding more expenses, I keep presenting new input boxes and keep displaying the totalofExpenses
- If user go back to previously added expense item and make a change say change the amount I want to update my total.

Following is the code the way I am trying to achieve the above described functionality. It is NOT working as it supposed to be.
Note: I am trying to put only the code that is relevant for this issue

```
      var data = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
       //Add total expenses  TotalShiftExpenses
    var mappingOptionsForTotalShiftExpenses = {
        create: function(options) {
            return new ComputeTotalShiftExpenses(options.data);
        }
    };

    var Expense = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.ShiftId = ko.observable(@Model.Shift.Id),
            self.Id = ko.observable(0),
            self.Amount = ko.observable(0),
            self.Description = ko.observable("");
    }        

    function ComputeTotalShiftExpenses(data) {
        var self = this;
        var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        model.TotalShiftExpenses = ko.computed(function() {
            var sum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < model.Shift.ShiftExpenses().length; i++) {
                //                 if ((parseFloat(model.Shift.ShiftExpenses()[i].Amount)) > 0) {

                sum += parseFloat(model.Shift.ShiftExpenses()[i].Amount());

            }
           //Add empty Expense to Observable array
           if (parseFloat(model.Shift.ShiftExpenses()[ (model.Shift.ShiftExpenses().length - 1)].Amount()) > 0) {

                model.Shift.ShiftExpenses
                    .push( new Expense({ "ShiftId": 0, "Id": 0, "Amount": 0, "Description": "" }));

          }

            return sum.toFixed(2);
        });
        return model;
    }

        //Apply MappingOptions
      var AppViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptionsForTotalShiftExpenses);

        $(document)
        .ready(function() {

            ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);


        });
```

With the above code I am able to get
   - First input boxes for first expense item
   - Once I add expense item, it will show another input box set for next item and also display the total.
   - Issue is when I try to add the 2nd expense it doesn't trigger anything (it seems that 2nd set of input boxes are not observable). However, if I make the amount change in the first expense item, it will trigger the observable behavior and will correctly add items for both expesnse.. and add the UI input boxes for the 3rd expense. For some reason always the last input box does not trigger observable behavior but any box before the last will do.
Note: The code I posted is only trying to add amount of expense.

Desperately waiting to hear from some knockout expert.... thank a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have over-complicated things a little bit. It should really be very simple to map in your data and create a computed observable that tracks the total amount:

**Edit:** Updated to include the dynamic input box functionality. You can accomplish this by adding a few lines of code to the computed observable to guarantee that a blank item always exists at the bottom of the array:

```
// Data pulled in from wherever
var data = [{
  ShiftId: 1,
  Id: 1,
  Amount: 25.00,
  Description: 'Supplies'
}, {
  ShiftId: 2,
  Id: 2,
  Amount: 20.00,
  Description: 'Lunch'
}];

// Expense model
var Expense = function(shiftId, id, amount, desc) {
  var self = this;
  self.ShiftId = ko.observable(shiftId);
  self.Id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Amount = ko.observable(amount);
  self.Description = ko.observable(desc);
};

//  Main ViewModel
var AppViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  // Expenses array
  self.Expenses = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

  // Compute the grand total of all expenses
  self.TotalofExpenses = ko.computed(function() {
    // First, ensure that a blank item remains at the bottom of array
    self.Expenses.remove(function(item) {
        return !item.Amount() && !item.Description();
    });
    self.Expenses.push(new Expense());

    // Now calculate the sum of all expenses
    var total = 0;
    self.Expenses().forEach(function(item, index) {
      total += +item.Amount() || 0;
    });

    return total;
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

**Edit 2:** Updated the JSFiddle so that the Amount input boxes are disabled until the user provides a value for the Description input (see HTML in the JSFiddle link). I did this by simply adding 'enable: Description' to the binding for the Amount input box.

https://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/aaysdxmb/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, what you have posted is already working for me. My issue is to add dynamic input boxes and get their total. Would you please add that functionality in your solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Answer has been updated to include dynamically adding and removing form elements as the user enters data.

Comment: Thanks a million. Actually I can not say Thank you enough. I have marked it as an answer. If you can add a little update I will appreciate a lot. If you can make it such the description has to be entered before the amount can be entered.

Comment: Sure, check the JSFiddle link. I have updated it so that it contains a new binding which will disable the Amount input boxes unless a description has been provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis it is working exactly as I wanted. God bless you buddy.

Comment: Since you have created a nice JSFiddle that have resolved my issue and I have learned some basic concepts. There is one more question that I want your help to clarify. Let's say If I want to add another set of functionality such as follows: 1- Show similar way dynamic input fields for Cash deposit amounts and show total at the bottom. This will require another cashdeposit array and a computed function TotalCashDeposits. How would you expand the current JSFiddle to add this functionality. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen my previous comment. Would you please expand the existing fiddle to add another observable array cashdeposits and a computed function of TotalDeposit. I need similar functionality a growing input boxes for each deposit and a total at the bottom. I want to see what is the proper way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for the attempt that I made. It partially work. I can add cash deposit but if I change the existing amount of a deposit it does not trigger the sum  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqrh5cdj/6/)

Comment: You're very close to having the correct code. There is just one thing you need to change. Because the CashDeposit object does not include a description field, you must remove the description validation from the computed observable. Remove '&& !item.Description()' from line 70 in your JsFiddle.

Comment: you have helped me resolve this issue. However I ran into another issue that I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309029/knockout-computed-observable-array-from-other-observable-arrays). Nobody has reponded. Would you please guide me what I am doing wrong there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you've said I've created a simple fiddle where the number of input fields are controlled by a `ko.observableArray` and the `foreach` binding. When you add or remove(remove not in fiddle) items from the array the view is automatically updated. In your case it seems there is more functionality and other special checks you'll want to make but I believe this should help you with what you are trying to accomplish.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8p1ucw6/3/)

```js
function TestVM() {
  this.inputFields = ko.observableArray([
    { type: 'type1', displayName: 'name1' },
    { type: 'type2', displayName: 'name2' },
    { type: 'type3', displayName: 'name3' }
  ]);
}

var dynamic = new TestVM();
ko.applyBindings(dynamic);

$('#addInput').click(function(){
dynamic.inputFields.push({ type: 'newtype', displayName: 'newField' });
  console.log(dynamic.inputFields());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: inputFields">
    <label data-bind="text: $data.displayName"></label><br>
    <input data-bind="name: $data.type"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="addInput">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I saw your fiddle. I want to add a new input box without click of a button. Moreover, I also want to have a running total of all the amounts entered in the input boxes.

Comment: Right and that's what I meant, all you'll have to do behind the scenes is add to that array instead of how its hooked into the click event now. The button click was just the initiator of adding new buttons in this example. As for the running total amounts in the binding simply add the text binding to the foreach in the view(http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html).