# Knockout Computed Observable Array from other Observable Arrays

Tags: knockout-3.0

I am using knockout with my ASP.NET Core project to achieve following
1- I am trying to compute the sold inventory based upon opening, closing and delivery inventory of a product.

I have four arrays. `OpeeningInventories`,`ClosingInventories`, `DeliveredInventories` and `SoldInventories`. I am creating these arrays identically at the server side. Each array have a number of GasProducts (model). I have created JSFiddle to show you the code. Sorry the code somewhat works in my project but it is not working in JSFiddle. I will greatly appreciate if you can help me fix my problem. Thanks in advance. Here is the link to [JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/am6qvu13/15/)

Comment: I am not sure why my SoldInventories array always have volume of each item as 0 on the UI. However, I put some alert messages on the computed function there the array show the correct values. I am very confused and have wasted lot of time. I will greatly appreciate if someone can guide me to the right direction. Below is the code of the computed function

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/am6qvu13/20/)